# How to add rounded corner as a background of Recyclerview that When scrolling items works in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I know this solution can add a background to the Recyclerview . But the background is static. I want the background can scroll as the Recyclerview does

[image: screenShot]

Comment: How big is your data set? It sounds like you probably want to use a `CardView` hosting a `NestedScrollView` hosting a `RecyclerView` that uses `wrap_content` for the height. Note that using `wrap_content` will defeat the entire _recycling_ point of `RecyclerView`, so if your data set is large you will experience performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following heirarchy of  layouts:

1. ScrollView
2. CardView with 0 elevation and rounded corners
3. Relative Layout with wrap content
4. RecyclerView